# Get the current Node in JSP with Jahia?

Tags: jahia

Is there a way to get the current node you are with Jahia ?

I tried to find in the documentation, but Jahia's not greatly documented.

tried to use ${node.path} but didn't gave me what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${renderContext.mainResource.node.path} is the solution.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  This would get you a path to the rendered resource, not the node in the context of where the renderer is currently working.  ${currentNode} is a reference that is always in context to the node that the renderer is parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Use ${currentNode} to get the current node you are.

```
<%--@elvariable id="currentNode" type="org.jahia.services.content.JCRNodeWrapper"--%>
${currentNode}
```

https://academy.jahia.com/documentation